# Using Server.MapPath in external C# Classes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, path, relative-path

I'm trying to get the absolute path of certain files in a C# class.  `Server.MapPath` works great of course for ASPX and their code-behind pages, but that doesn't exist in another class file.  I tried `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`, but that complains that the relative virtual path isn't allowed.  Any thoughts?

`System.Web` is already imported.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

The `ServerUtility` class is available as an instance in your `HttpContext`.  If you're in an environment where you know it'll be executed inside the ASP.Net pipeline, you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()
```

You'll have to import `System.Web` though.

Comment: Even though this post is more than 2 years old, you've helped me tremendously. Thanks.

Comment: What if it is not executed in that pipeline?

Comment: If you're not executing inside of ASP.Net then it's unlikely that your HttpContext is being set, unless you wrote your own pipeline :)  You'll have to rely on whatever methods your execution context (router?) provides.   If your process has insight to the basics of your path routing you can take a look at the System.IO.Path methods.

Comment: This compiled but context is null outside of controllers, so my code errors. I think womp is saying the same thing there. If thats the case can you access MapPath outside of the routers?

Answer (score 35):

you can also use:

```
var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/myfile.txt")
```

if

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var fullpath = Path.Combine(path , "myfile.txt");
```

is inaccessible

Answer (score 10):

Can't you just add a reference to `System.Web` and then you can use `Server.MapPath` ?

Edit: Nowadays I'd recommend using the [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx):

It's a static method in `System.Web` assembly that Maps a virtual path to a physical path on the server. It *doesn't* require a reference to `HttpContext`.

Comment: Sure you can add the reference to an external class; but obviously you need to use it in the context of a server request so HttpContext is not null.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(type).Location
```

IF the file you are trying to get is the assembly location for a type.  But if the files are relative to the assembly location then you can use this with `System.IO` namespace to get the exact path of the file.

Comment: -1: What led you to believe he wanted the location of an assembly?

Comment: He said "certain files" he didn't specify the location or nature of the files, thus knowing the assembly location and being able to work relative to that path can be helpful.  Of course if he actually stated he was still in a HttpContext then I wouldn't have bothered answering.

Comment: David McEwing, what you suggest won't work because IIS doesn't load the assemblies from the location that you install them in, in the web site.   They are copied and loaded from a temporary asp.net cache location, so doing a GetAssembly or GetExecutingAssembly will point you to the location of the assembly, but it would have nothing to do with the location of the web site that MapPath points to.

Answer (score 4):

I use this too:

```
System.Web.HTTPContext.Current.Server.MapPath
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class test
{
public static void useServerPath(string path)
{
   if (File.Exists(path)
{
 \\...... do whatever you wabt
}
else
{
\\.....
}
}
```

Now when you call the method from the codebehind

for example :

```
protected void BtAtualizacao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string path = Server.MapPath("Folder") + "\\anifile.txt";

            test.useServerPath(path);
}
```

in this way your code is to simple and with one method u can use multiple path for each call :)

Answer (score 3):

This one helped for me

```
//System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath //        
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"),
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Little more explanation would help out the fellow programmers to understand why the solution worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you're running within the context of ASP.NET or not, you should be able to use HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath

Answer (score 0):

**The server.mappath("") will work on aspx page,if you want to get the absolute path from a class file you have to use this-**

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailLogic/RegistrationTemplate.html")
```